# What's is the name of this function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A function, $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, is defined in the following way,
\begin{align}
f(n)=\#\{m\mid m\leq n, \text{ and there does not exists an integer }m' \in (m,n]\text{ such that } m|m'\}.
\end{align}
I want to know the name of this function, and I am also curious about properties of this function.

Thank everyone for helping.

Comment: is $m$ a real number or an integer?

Comment: So ... $7$ is not counted in $f(10)$, because there exists $14>7$ such that $7$ divides $14$?

Comment: m is an integer

Comment: so $f(10)=\#\{10, 9, 8, 7, 6\}=5$

Comment: I have to admit I can't think of a name for this function, really.

Comment: Hint: for a given $n$, a number $m$ satisfies your condition "there does not exist any $m'$ such that ..." iff $2m > n$. So $f(n)$ is closely related to $n/2$.

Comment: Why is 5 not in the set for f(10)?   there is no $m'<10$  such that $5|m'$  and $m'>5$

Comment: sorry. That is a typo. I've fixed that

Answer (score 0):

As hinted at by Rob [in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313783/whats-is-the-name-of-this-function#comment2668884_1313783), your function can more succinctly be written as $f(n) = \lceil n/2 \rceil$.

- Every number $a \leq \frac{1}{2}n$ will not be counted, because $a|2a$ and $2a \leq n$.
- Every number $a > \frac{1}{2}n$ will be counted because every number $a$ divides will be greater than $n$: $$n < 2a < 3a < 4a < \dotsb \,.$$

So then for each $n$ how many positive integers $a$ are there such that $\frac{1}{2}n < a \leq n$? Play around for a bit, and you'll see that there are $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ of them, where $\lceil x \rceil$ is the *ceiling* of $x$ and denotes the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$.